# i am getting error:object reference not set to an instance of object

Tags: android, xamarin

I am getting when trying to set navigation mode how to resolve it

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true)]

public class MainActivity : Activity,ActionBar.ITabListener {

     private ActionBar ab;
     protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
      {

        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        try{
           //here i am getting instance of action  bar
            ab = ActionBar;
        **i am getting error at this line **

                     ab.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;


            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);



}
}
```

Comment: [Mono] AOT module 'System.Core.dll.so' not found: Cannot load library: load_library[1108]: Library '/data/data/Finall.Finall/lib/System.Core.dll.so' not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code, with the only exception that i did not impliment the ITabListener, and it works.

```
[Activity (Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true)]

    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        private ActionBar ab;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {

            base.OnCreate (bundle);


try {
            //here i am getting instance of action  bar
            ab = ActionBar;
        **i am getting error at this line **

            ab.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;


            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);



        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

}
```

I have never seen someone using an actionbar by implimenting the ITabListener ( on xamarin ). I would sugest you take the xamarin way of building up an actionbar. [Here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/actionbar/) is a link to the documentation.